# Thunderbird compose email in batch script - use template.html on body

Tags: html, templates, batch-file, thunderbird, document-body

So, I'm trying to use this batch in windows to generate an email but I can't figure out a way to use a template.html as body for the email.

I'm following this http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_-_Thunderbird

It's actually just a matter of reading the html file and either passing it as argument or pasting it as the body (same result).

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an error message or something like that? What is not working as expected?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [Bug 882104 - Command line option to read message body from file](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=882104) at Bugzilla@Mozilla.